# How get real path from Uri of Audio File in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, uri

I am trying to get the real path of audio file form uri and I've used a method to do this job but I did not get expected result, it always returns null.

code I've tried

**getAudioPathFromUri**

```
public String getAudioPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
    String path = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.v(TAG,"real path :::: "+path);//this displays null
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Without even looking at the other functions, it is obvious that cursor.moveToFirst() is returning false and therefore skipping the body of your if statement.

Comment: aye ok, then what should i do to make body of if executable

Comment: Read into what specifically is causing cursor.moveToFirst() to return false. I'm not sure how you're debugging this. We need the code of moveToFirst() as well in order to possibly see why it is returning false. [We need more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: moveToFirst() is inbuilt method of cursor, sir

Comment: Well reading here, [it returns false if the cursor is empty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToFirst()). Why is the cursor empty? It has to be a bad usage of your assignment command.

Comment: I found the solution bro. Thank you for your fast response.